# Sidekiq flags clarification

Tags: sidekiq

Does this sidekiq command `sidekiq -c 2 -q default` mean that we create a queue named default with 2 concurrent workers?

Wiki doesn't explicitly tell us whether what each flag means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sidekiq -h
sidekiq [options]
    -c, --concurrency INT            processor threads to use
    -q, --queue QUEUE[,WEIGHT]       Queues to process with optional weights
```